I want to add another type based on the type of C language code
#include "stdio.h"

#define TYPE_DATA_DEFINE(name) \
    name; \
    unsigned char name##valid;\

#define TYPE_DATA_SET(name, value) \
    name##valid = 1; \
    name = value;    \

#define TYPE_DATA_GET(name, value) \
    (name##valid == 1 ? (value = name, 1) : 0)

#define TYPE_DATA_CLEAR(name) \
    name = 0;    \
    name##valid = 0; \

struct hh {
    unsigned char TYPE_DATA_DEFINE(max);
    unsigned char TYPE_DATA_DEFINE(min);
};

int main(void)
{
    struct hh hhs = { 0 };
    unsigned char tmp;

    if (SSWL_TYPE_DATA_GET(hhs.max, tmp)) {
        printf("info, tmp:(%u)", tmp);
    } else {
        printf("info, tmp:(%u)", tmp);
    }

    return 0;
}

I want to add another type based on the type of C language code. This type retains the original arbitrary type, but adds a valid field of unsigned char type on this basis.

Before obtaining the current data, first determine whether the data is valid. If valid, return the data. If invalid, return 0.
When setting data, set the valid field to valid while assigning data.

But I encountered two problems. I wonder if anyone has a good solution:

When using GET and SET, the compiler will not warn if the types do not match. However, this is not allowed for writing safe C code. How can we maintain the above functions while having parameter type checking function.
My macro does not support array definition. Is there a good way to implement array definition?

I considered C11's _Static_assert syntax and GNU's #define static_assert(condition) 
In the form of typedef char static_assert_failed[(condition) ? 1 : -1], is there a better way?

OT: Why do you want to turn a C program into something that is not C? Have you considered using a different language that already has the guardrails that you desire built-in?

This is a question and answer site. Note that question is singular, not plural. If you have two separate questions, they need to be in separate posts. You should go back and revisit the [tour] and [help] pages to better understand how the site works.

I think the main issue here is that this is an XY Problem.

Sorry, thank you for your advice, because I didn't learn English well when I was in school. I will improve my English level in the future.



When using GET and SET, the compiler will not warn if the types do not match. However, this is not allowed for writing safe C code. How
can we maintain the above functions while having parameter type
checking function.



Macros are not functions.  The only function in the code presented is main().

Macro invocations expand to C source code.  If you want warnings about assignments with inexactly-matching types then that has nothing in particular to do with your use of macros, as such warnings would be based on the resulting expanded code.

What diagnostics your compiler might emit is between you and and it. Any given one might or might not have facilities for diagnosing the situations you ask about.
If you happen to be using GCC then turning on -Wconversion may get you the diagnostics you want (I equivocate because I'm not sure I understand exactly what you want here).  Other compilers that emulate GCC command-line options (Clang, icc, ...) may also support that one.  Compilers that do not emulate gcc options might have their own version.




My macro does not support array definition. Is there a good way to implement array definition?


I don't think there's anything particularly good about your macro stack.  However, you can get it to support arrays by adding parameters for a dimension / index.  Note well that macro arguments can consist of no tokens at all, which is what you would use with scalars.  Example:
#define TYPE_DATA_DEFINE(name, dim) \
    name dim; \
    unsigned char name##valid;\

#define TYPE_DATA_SET(name, index, value) \
    name##valid = 1; \
    name index = value;    \

#define TYPE_DATA_GET(name, index, value) \
    (name##valid == 1 ? (value = name index, 1) : 0)

#define TYPE_DATA_CLEAR(name, index) \
    name index = 0;    \
    name##valid = 0; \

struct hh {
    unsigned char TYPE_DATA_DEFINE(scalar,);
    unsigned char TYPE_DATA_DEFINE(array, [3]);
};

int main(void)
{
    struct hh hhs = { 0 };
    unsigned char tmp = 42;

    if (TYPE_DATA_GET(hhs.scalar,, tmp)) {
        printf("info, tmp:(%u)", tmp);
    } else {
        printf("info, tmp:(%u)", tmp);
    }

    if (TYPE_DATA_GET(hhs.array, [1], tmp)) {
        printf("info, tmp:(%u)", tmp);
    } else {
        printf("info, tmp:(%u)", tmp);
    }

    return 0;
}

If you want array members to have arrays of validity flags, then you can modify the above to do that.
BUT DON'T.  Don't do any of this.  It's awful, and there's no way to make it very much better.  I dislike not only the implementation but also the whole underlying idea of per-member validity tags.

And also, empty macro arguments didn't appear until C99.

C99 is 25 years old. You’d be hard-pressed to find a good reason to require support for anything older.

@Neil, C17 is the current language spec, with C2X (perpetually) imminent.  Questions about C unqualified by a language version or a specific implementation are about C17.  If the OP wanted an answer for C90, a 34-year old, long obsolete version of the language, then the onus was on them to say so.  And if they did, then that is all the more reason to heed my closing comments: don't do any of this.
